# Service Worker was updated because "Update on reload" was checked in the DevTools Application panel

Tags: service-worker

What does this warning mean? why it shows up here?

[image]

The service worker "Update on reload" warning.

Comment: Ok. So what's your issue?

Comment: @Rodiwa Did not understand, why this warning was coming up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Update on reload" option was checked in the Application > Service workers

[image]

Comment: I want to implement push notification. Can you please guide me in implementing the steps. One question I have - Can we implement full push notification flow only at client side or any backend server required ?

Comment: @DebugDiva as of my knowledge it needs to be implemented at server side, a push notificaton provider like one signal or google cloud messaging and at front end , need to add libraries to connect all these together.  Use bard or Chatgpt to get the info you need